# Excel VBA - run-time error '1004: Select method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have the following Excel VBA code,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    myMacro
End Sub





Public Sub myMacro()


    If Range("C4").Value = "Sales" Then

            Range("E4:AB5").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0"


    Else

             Range("E4:AB5").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

    End If

End Sub
```

My problem is the cell "C4" references from a drop down menu in a different sheet via a vlookup.  Each time I get the following error,

```
'run-time error '1004: Select method of Range class failed' and it does not work.
```

If the cell "C4" references from the same sheet it works, however I need it to reference from a different sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't completely clear but if you want to look up `C4` in a different sheet (I have used `Sheet2` as an example), and then format the activesheet (no need to `Select`) you could try:

```
Public Sub myMacro()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

If ws.Range("C4").Value = "Sales" Then
    Range("E4:AB5").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0"
Else
    Range("E4:AB5").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry - I'll try to make it a little clearer!  In my original code cell 'C4' determines the format of the range.  If 'C4' returns 'Sales', the format will be include a currency symbol, if it returns something else it will use the other format (This is all in the same sheet - Sheet 1).  The contents of 'C4' are linked to cell in a different sheet (eg Sheet 2) - this is where I get my error.  If 'C4' links to a cell within the same sheet (Sheet 1) it works, but when I link it to a different sheet (Sheet 2) it doesn't.  Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: What is the C4 formula, if this is the part that is failing? :)

Comment: it works in the sheet, not sure if it causing the code to fail.  I'll try to explain...in cell 'C5' I have the following formula (to trigger the macro) =IF(OR(C4="Sales",C4="Applications"),myMacro,"").  In cell 'C4' I have the following formula =VLOOKUP(A2,Mapping!D:E,2,FALSE).  Cell 'A2' references from a different sheet....='Chart (ALL)'!A1:D1.  I hope that makes sense!!!

Comment: basically what I am trying to do is change format of a range based on the outcome of cell 'C4' - which is formula driven (ultimately referencing from a different sheet).  If 'C4' returns 'Sales' then do one format, if it returns 'Applications' do the other format.